# Calculate limes of sum((n,k)k!/(2k+1)!!)) from 0 to n

Tags: calculus

The following limit should be infinity.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{n\choose k} \cdot k!}{(2k+1)!!})$

where ${n\choose k}$ is the binomial coefficient and k!! = $k \cdot (k-2) \cdot (k-4) \cdot...$.

What about:

$\lim_{{n \to \infty}} \left( \frac{\sum_{{k=0}}^{n} \frac{{n \choose k} \cdot k!}{{(2k+1)!!}}}{2^{2n}} \right)
$?

Numerically, this limit goes to zero for me.

My question is: How does $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{n\choose k} \cdot k!}{(2k+1)!!}$ behave in the long term? Can I say that it behaves like $2^{\alpha n}$? What is $\alpha$?

I plotted $2^{\alpha n} / \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{{n\choose k} \cdot k!}{(2k+1)!!}$ in Python and it approaches a value of ~4.7 for n=150 and $\alpha$=0.58. But I don't know if it converges to this value, as I can't go beyond 150 numerically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your summation is $S=\sum \binom{n}{k}\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\dots\cdot k}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot\dots \cdot(2k+1)}$.

Easy to see that $\sum\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}\frac{1}{2k+1}<S<\sum\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$, you get the l.h.s if you pair the numbers vertically, and r.h.s if you ignore the first 1 on the bottom then pair them up.

The r.h.s is easy to evaluate, $\sum\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k=(1+\frac{1}{2})^n=1.5^n$.

The l.h.s can be bounded as

$\sum\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}\frac{1}{2k+1}>
\sum\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}\frac{1}{2k+2}=
\sum\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k\frac{1}{k+1}=
\frac{1}{n+1}\sum\frac{(n+1)!}{(k+1)!(n-k)!}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k=
\frac{2}{n+1}((1+\frac{1}{2})^{n+1}-1)$

which also approaches $1.5^n$. This matches the result you got, $2^{0.58}=1.495$.